# Redundant #include in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, cmake, qmake

Suppose now I have three source files: ClassA.hpp, ClassB.hpp, and ClassC.hpp.

ClassB inherits from ClassA, and ClassC inherits from ClassB.

So, in ClassB.hpp, I wrote #include "ClassA.hpp".
Then, in ClassC.hpp, besides including ClassB.hpp, shall I also include ClassA.hpp?

When writing Makefiles, should I make a ClassA.o a dependency of ClassC.o?
And in cmake -- if I don't write #include "ClassA.hpp" in ClassC.hpp, ClassA.o will not be a dependency of ClassC.o, right? Is that ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does ClassC.hpp require the contents of ClassA.hpp, disregarding ClassB.hpp for the time being?

If so, then yes, you should include it and not rely on a round-about accidental include that could change. Checking that and setting up the proper includes should be relatively simple. Relying on another file or behavior that may change later is poor practice, and should not be used.

***Edit:*** In the case of inheritance, which the question applies to, things are a bit different. This is a case where you *can* rely on B requiring A, and it could be said you don't directly rely on A (if B changed to inherit from Q, C could no longer need A). You want to look at what a header, or class, depends on and include the file providing that. If it relies on something directly, include it directly.

Including a header multiple times can be made harmless with the use of header guards and is very common in larger code bases.

Comment: Currently in Class[ABC].hpp there's only definition of Class[ABC]. So under this circumstance, I don't need to include ClassA.hpp in ClassC.hpp at all, even though ClassC derives from ClassA, right?

Comment: Will ClassC.hpp compile properly without including ClassA or ClassB? That's the test you want. If ClassC derives from ClassA, the code fails the test and you do need to include them. If C and B both inherit A, then include only A from each; if C inherits B which inherits A, then include B (this may be the only case where you should rely on B including A),

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the make, ClassC.o should not depend on ClassA.o.  It should have a dependency on ClassA.hpp, which will normally be generated even though it is included indirectly through ClassB.hpp.

I like to have ClassB.hpp include ClassA.hpp explicitly if it relies on stuff defined in ClassA.hpp.  I think it is cleaner that way.

Comment: ClassA is the base class of ClassB. So why not include it? Will some guys just write "class ClassA;" in ClassB.hpp then start writing ClassB without including ClassA.hpp?

Comment: So when ClassA.hpp changes, ClassC.o do not need to be recompiled?

Comment: Yes, when ClassA.hpp changes, ClassC (.cpp) will need to be recompiled.  I'm assuming that your .hpp files are header files, and they normally change less frequently than the associated .cpp files.  If ClassA.cpp changes, but the .hpp does not, then ClassC does not need to be recompiled.  Does that fit your situation?